# Set background position in react-native-web Image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, background-image, react-native-web

I'm trying to "center top" a image that is larger than my view using `<Image />` component from react-native-web.
For default, react-native web sets background-position to "center" but this is resulting in the view losing the top part of the image.
Anyone know how to set this property? or other aproch to center top the image